# Rename file in Mac OS Terminal using Regex

Tags: regular-expression, osx, bash, terminal, rename

Hundreds of images need to be renamed with a terminal command using regex on MacOS 10.9 Mavericks.

The files are named this way:

```
0045AW489R3T(IPCAM)_0_20131124101245_931.jpg
0021DF025C8E(IPCAM)_0_20131127101721_44591.jpg
389223GT4Z6W(IPCAM)_0_20131128103423_7893282.jpg
```

They need to be renamed to this:

```
2013-11-24  10-12-45.jpg
2013-11-27  10-17-21.jpg
2013-11-28  10-34-23.jpg
```

Can anyone please show me how to do it?

Comment: Why do you want to use a regular expression?

Comment: You might find the answer to this question a guide to what you want to do. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278391/changing-include-filenames-to-match-case

Comment: I just assumed that a regular expression would be the only way to do it. Now I know that I was wrong.

Comment: Yeah, if its fixed format, probably don't need a regex. But, if badly formed filename sneaks in, a regex can give you more options for a recovery.

Comment: Not complete, but I use something like: `for a in *; do b=$(echo $a | perl -pe 's/^\d(\d\d)/\1/'); mv "$a" "$b"; done`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try

```
for a in *.jpg ; do mv -- "$a" "${a:22:4}-${a:26:2}-${a:28:2} ${a:30:2}-${a:32:2}-${a:34:2}.jpg" ; done
```

A bit ugly, but it should get the job done. Like always, make sure to test on a copy before.

Comment: Are the ${a:22:4} substrings? start at character 22 and pull 4 characters?

Comment: Yes they are. Assuming, as the in example, that all strings are formatted the same way.

Comment: This works, I was able to embedd this into my Hazel.app folder action as intended. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If the first part of the filenames don't always have the same length, you can use [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) to extract the string after the second `_` and use the first 8 digits to construct your filename:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for file in folder/*; do
    outName=$(awk -F"_" '{ print substr($3,1,4)"-"substr($3,5,2)"-"substr($3,7,2) }' <<< "${file}").jpg
    mv "${file}" "${outName}"
done
```